# How can I test that some specific element comes before another specific element in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, dependencies

I had a problem whereby a list of jobs, each represented by a character `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` etc, had to be sorted given that some of them depended on other jobs. So if job `"a"` depended on `"b"`, and `"b"` and `"c"` didn't depend on any job, the list `'abc'` would be sorted as `'bac'`, simple.

My problem is I want to write a test to check that jobs come after the jobs they depend on in the output array.

#### Example

If job `"c"` depends on job `"f"`, how can I test that `"f"` is before `"c"` in

```
array = ["a", "b", "f", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: `arr.index('f') < arr.index('c')`. See [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-index). This assumes that `arr` contains both `'f'` and `'c'`, as `arr.index('x') #=> nil` if `arr` does not contain `'x'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already most of the solution in the comment by Cary Swoveland. Here is a full example which takes care of all the cases (no c, no f, neither, wrong order, ok)

```
jobs = %w[a b f c d e]

index_c = jobs.index('c')
index_f = jobs.index('f')

if index_c && index_f && index_c > index_f
  puts "Everything is fine"
elsif index_c && index_f
  puts "job c is before job f"
elsif !index_c && !index_f
  puts "jobs are missing"
elsif !index_c
  puts "no job c"
else
  puts "no job f"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a hash with the job and its dependency, for instance and as in your example if job `c` depends on `f` and `b` depends on `a`, then:

```
hash  = {c: 'f', b: 'a'}
```

So, over your hash you can use `map` to get a "plain" array where you check if the index of the hash value in your array is minor than the index of the hash key (to string) also in the array, if so, then you add `true`, then checking for all values within the array, all must be `true`:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e']
result = hash.map{|k,v| array.index(v) < array.index(k.to_s)}
p result.all?{|e| e} # => true
```

So, using Minitest, you can test `result.all?{|e| e}.eql?` is equal to `true`:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_a_job_is_before_its_dependency
    hash   = {c: 'f', b: 'a'}
    array  = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    result = hash.map{|k,v| array.index(v) < array.index(k.to_s)}.all?{|e| e}
    assert result.equal? true
  end
end
```

Comment: I've always thought that Ruby should define `TrueClass#true?` so you can convert `result.all?{|e| e}` to `result.all?(&:true?)`.

Answer (score 2):

The best data format for this problem would be a [dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph) or a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

To get a suitable array of jobs, you'd need [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), e.g. using [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm) or a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search).

[`Plexus`](https://github.com/chikamichi/plexus) gem offers a topological sort.

```
require 'plexus'

include Plexus

dg = Digraph["a","b", "a","f", "f","c", "f","d", "d","e", "b","f"]

p dg.topsort
# ["a", "b", "f", "d", "e", "c"]

require 'plexus/dot'
dg.write_to_graphic_file('png','visualize')
```

[image]

All you need to check is if the resulting array is empty or not:

```
require 'plexus'

include Plexus
dg = Digraph["c","a", "a","b", "b","a"] 
p dg.topsort
# []
```

[image]

If it's empty, there's at least one cycle in your dependencies, and no array can be found. If the array's not empty, it includes every element in a correct order. No need to check it further.